# ImportError: No module named requests tried to install requests modeule but it's already fullfilled by other python version

Tags: python, linux, kali-linux

I tried to run a python script but had the error

```
ImportError: No module named requests
```

Tried to install module called requests but got another error

```
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (2.21.0)
WARNING: Running pip as root will break packages and permissions. You should install packages reliably by using venv: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
```

I can't troubleshoot it any more already wasted 3 days to find the solution.

[image: screenshot of the error]

Answer (score 1):

Your pip uses python3. This is what the path here says:

```
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (2.21.0)
                                                          ^
```

But you run your script with python2. The output of `python --version` proves this.

Execute your script with `python3 48506.py` and it should work.

---

Otherwise check your pip version `pip -V`. The python version should match with `python -V`.

It's generally recommended to use `python -m pip`. This ensures that you use the same python version for pip as for your script.

Comment: Hi tried with python 3 it show me error like "SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(Style.BRIGHT+Fore.RED+"[!] "+Fore.RESET+"Could not connect to the webshell."+Style.RESET_ALL)"

Comment: @ArshdeepKhakh The error-message tells you all you need to know. In py3 print is only a function, in py2 this was a statement. See https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function. So you have to replace `print "print this"` with `print("print this")`.

Comment: Thx that helped at lot. I have to change few things to get rid of the errors. I run the script with py3 for the last time and the script stopped with "<function header at 0x7f4005731670>" thing. I tired to google it but can't find anything useful